# Possible orbital angular momentum values in the weak decay of $B_s \rightarrow J/\psi+\phi$

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, standard-model

So $B_s$ has $J=0$, and both the decay products have $J=1$. $J$ is conserved, so the joint final state must also have $J=0$, and I'm told the final joint state can have orbital angular momentum values of $L= 0$, $1$, or $2$, but I have no idea how to show this.

I am finding angular momentum addition in general very difficult to get my head around, so any help with the steps involved to get this result would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***J*** consists of intrinsic or spin vector angular momentum, ***S***, and orbital vector angular momentum, ***L*** adding like vectors. The  ***J*** of the l.h.side is pure ***S=0***, and the scalar value in its casimir is just *J=0*.

Each of the two spins on the right are 1, so you need the 3 vectors
$$ {\mathbf S}_\psi + {\mathbf S}_\phi + {\mathbf L}=0.$$
As you learn in undergraduate QM, two spin-one operators may "add", symmetrically to a spin-2 or spin-0 object, or, antisymmetrically, to a spin-1 object, as the *J* in the addition of two such ranges from $|J_1+J_2|$ to $|J_1-J_2|$, in integral steps.

So, in the 3 cases listed above, your *J* =2; 1; 0 can only be cancelled to zero, the initial *J*, and so ***J***, by the addition of *J=L=* 2; 1; 0, respectively.

[image]

---

*Response to comment*

No; angular momentum does not add that way. **L** and **S** are both **J** entities, and their  freaky Casimir "magnitudes" add like *J*s, in the above tell-tale nonabelian way.

So, calling **L**= **J**$_3$, you are to add
${\mathbf J}_1$ to ${\mathbf J}_2$ to ${\mathbf J}_3$, to get ${\mathbf J}_{initial}=0$, as in the displayed equation above.

How do you add 1 to 1 and *L* to get 0? If 1 and 1 are 2, you add a 2 to get a zero. If 1 and 1 are 1, you add a 1 to get 0. And if 1 and 1 are 0, you can only maintain 0 by adding 0.

Recall all this "nonabelian addition" imagery represents an elaborate tensor "coproduct", and of course, ${\mathbf J} \cdot {\mathbf J}= J(J+1)~{\mathbb I}$, in your informal QM language. So, when ***J***=0, you must have *J*=0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I don't understand how $J_{initial} =0$ yet $J_{final} \in (0, 1, 2) $  (I thought $J_{final} = J_{initial} $ by momentum conservation?), but continuing down that road, I then find that $J_{final} \in (0, 1, 2) $ and $S_{final} \in (0, 1, 2) $,  then going on to show that $J=L+S \implies L=|J-S| \forall J, S \in (0, 1, 2) $.  This is the only way I can seem to get the result $L \in (0, 1, 2)$ and it feels wrong.

Comment: Ok, so I have $J_{initial} = 0 = S_{\psi} + S_{\phi} + L$ where $S_{\psi} + S_{\phi} \in (0, 1, 2) \implies (S_{\psi} + S_{\phi}) + L \in (|0-L|, |1-L|, |2-L|, ..., L, 1+L, 2+L)$ ? Sorry if this is frustrating for you, I am an undergrad and I'm learning all of this for the first time.  Statements like "if 1 and 1 are 2, you add a 2 to get a zero" are quite confusing! It makes sense to me for the $|0-L|$, $|1-L|$, $|2-L|$ and $L$ elements, which imply that $L = 0$, $1$, $2$, and $0$ respectively, but not for $1+L$ and $2+L$ as $L \in (0, 1, 2)$  and it needs to equal zero.  Thanks again.

Comment: Remember the point is to get *L* to be able to get the sum of the two spins, 2,1, or 0, to the target 0. Not every combination is interesting. If you add 0 to 0, you get 0. If you add 1 to 1, you *can* get 0, which you only care about (ignoring the possibilities 1 and 2). If you add 2 to 2, you also can get 0 (and you don't really care about 1,2,3,4, which you might also get). There are symmetry and antisymmetry considerations, but let's not go there...

Comment: Ahhh so I disregard all others except for the ones which give me the J-state I need.  I understand now.  Really, thank you, you've helped me understand where I am going wrong.